# Display list of Custom Post

Tags: custom-post-types, sub-menu

I created Custom Post Type `News`. I would like to show the list of Custom Post `News` at a sub menu of `News Info`. How can I do that ?

[image]

My custom post type registration code is like below

```
public function register_custom_post_type () {

        $supports = array('title');

        $labels = array(
            'name' => _x('Newss', 'plural'),
            'singular_name' => _x('News', 'singular'),
            'name_admin_bar' => _x('News', 'admin bar'),
            'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'add new'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New News'),
            'new_item' => __('New News'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit News'),
            'view_item' => __('View News'),
            'all_items' => __('All Newss'),
            'search_items' => __('Search News'),
            'not_found' => __('No News Found.'),
        );

        $args = array(
            'supports' => $supports,
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'description' => 'News Information',
            'has_archive' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'show_in_menu' => 'edit.php?post_type=news'
        );

        register_post_type('news', $args);
    }
```

My Menu code is like below

```
public function admin_menu()
{
    add_menu_page(‘News Information’, ‘News Info’, ‘manage_options’, ‘news_info’, [$this, ‘api_key_page’], ‘dashicons-info-outline’, 30);
    add_submenu_page(‘news_info’, ‘News Information’, ‘API Key’, ‘manage_options’, ‘news_info_page’, [$this, ‘api_key_page’]);
    add_submenu_page(‘news_info’, ‘News Information’, ‘News’, ‘manage_options’, ‘edit.php?post_type=news’);
    remove_submenu_page(‘news_info’, ‘news_info’);
}
```

Comment: How did you register the `News` CPT and the `News Info` menu? Please add the code to your question. (`register_post_type()` and `add_menu_page()`)

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ. I updated my post as per your requirements with `News` CPT and the `News Info` menu code.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about this. Were you able to find a solution - if not, do you still need help with this?